# Test 2D Collision Immediately

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to be able to create / move a 2D collider (box collider) and test its collision data immediately, without waiting for Unity Physics to run.

p.s. I need to move collider in multiple places per scene in one frame and test collision in those multiple places.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To try collisions against the Scene, one can use [`Physics.BoxCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.BoxCast.html).

See this sample from the Unity Documentation:

```cs
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Test to see if there is a hit using a BoxCast
        //Calculate using the center of the GameObject's Collider(could also just use the GameObject's position), half the GameObject's size, the direction, the GameObject's rotation, and the maximum distance as variables.
        //Also fetch the hit data
        m_HitDetect = Physics.BoxCast(m_Collider.bounds.center, transform.localScale, transform.forward, out m_Hit, transform.rotation, m_MaxDistance);
        if (m_HitDetect)
        {
            //Output the name of the Collider your Box hit
            Debug.Log("Hit : " + m_Hit.collider.name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive with 2D colliders you can also just use something like:

```
GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().IsTouching();
```

This will simply just check if the 2D collider is touching another collider and you can pass a layermask to check for as well:

```
GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().IsTouching(LayerMask.NameToLayer("LayerYouWantToCheck"));
```